# Are there other Types of Tabs?

Tags: tab

Aside from standard and custom tab. Are there any other kinds of tab that I should know? I will appreciate if you give me some references. thanks!

Comment: There is no such thing as "Standard tab(s)" [in case of a tricky exam question] Also, updated link to the article: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_tabdef.htm&type=0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are four types of Tabs (exclusive native tabs):

> Custom tabs display custom object data or other web content embedded
>   in the application.
>
> - **Custom Object Tabs**—For your custom object data.
>      *Custom Object Tabs display the data of your custom object in a user interface tab. Custom object tabs look and function just like standard tabs.*
> - **Web Tabs**—For other web content
>      *Custom Web Tabs display any external Web-based application or Web page in a Salesforce tab. You can design Web tabs to include the sidebar or span across the entire page without the sidebar.*
> - **Visualforce Tabs**—For Visualforce pages
>      *Visualforce Tabs display data from a Visualforce page. Visualforce tabs look and function just like standard tabs.*
> - **Flexible Page Tabs**—For Flexible Pages, to include them in the Salesforce1 navigation menu.
>      *Flexible Page Tabs let you add Flexible Pages to the Salesforce1 navigation menu.*

Also,

> **Lightning Page tabs**- let you add Lightning Pages to the Salesforce1 navigation menu.

Subtab apps support only Web Tabs and Visualforce Tabs.

Reference: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dev_tabscreate.htm

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the tabs mentioned by @Ashwani, there are two more tabs available for Lightning experience

> **Lightning Component Tab**
>
> Lightning Component tabs allow you to add Lightning components to the
> navigation menu in Lightning Experience and the mobile app.
>
> You can't access the Lightning Component tab outside of the mobile
> app. For example, you can't access the Lightning Component tab from
> the full Salesforce site.
>
> **Lightning Page Tab**
>
> Lightning Page Tabs let you add Lightning Pages to the mobile app
> navigation menu.
>
> Lightning Page tabs don't work like other custom tabs. Once created,
> they don't show up on the All Tabs page when you click the Plus icon
> that appears to the right of your current tabs. Lightning Page tabs
> also don't show up in the Available Tabs list when you customize the
> tabs for your apps.

Comment: Is this still valid? "You can't access the Lightning Component tab outside of the mobile app. For example, you can't access the Lightning Component tab from the full Salesforce site.". I have several lightning component tabs that I'm able to access and interact with the lwc components in Salesforce site.

Comment: It seems like you're quoting the descriptions, it'd be great if you add a link to the actual page that you're referencing from. This allows people to acquire more information if they need to. Thanks!

Comment: Link is already present in the first answer. It is the same link